# Does HTML 5 offline functionality work for browsers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html, offline-caching

I've been at this for a few days now and am becoming more and more frustrated.  I'm getting inconsistent offline functionality results across Chrome, FF, and I've just started using Safari.

I'm developing a sandbox app using Asp .Net MVC 3.  Below is the structure of my application:

- Controllers/CarController
- Views/Car/Edit
- Views/Car/EditOffline
- Views/Car/Index

Out of the 3 views, Index is the only that has the manifest attribute defined.  Index is the view that is initially requested.  Below is the contents of my manifest:

```
CACHE MANIFEST

FALLBACK:
Car/Edit Car/EditOffline

#Version 1
```

Upon the first request of Index, the browser creates 3 entries in the Application Cache.  They are:

- localhost/Sandbox/Car, type = master
- localhost/Sandbox/Car/EditOffline, type = fallback
- localhost/Sandbox/Offline., type = manifest

The way I've been simulating offline behavior for all 3 browsers is by explicitly stopping IIS.  After, Index has been requested.  I shut down IIS and make a request to the Edit action.  The result is is EditOffline gets served up.  Now, when I the Index view again, I get a 404 error, but why?  I thought the browser would've have served up the cached version of that page?  When I re-requeset the Edit view (while still offline), I also get a 404 error, but why?  The browser served the EditOffline view previously so why do I get a 404 now? In FF, I've gotten it to work as expected a few times, but I made no code changes.  I explicitly deleted the offline cache, restarted the server, re-requested the index view and it magically worked.

Comment: Your browser probably still thinks you are online. In FF try forcing to go offline by clicking File -> Work Offline.
Also use the cache api to check if your data is really downloaded and available offline. Don't forget to include your .css and .js files in your manifest.

Comment: @ZippyV Whether the browser thinks it's online or not is not all that relevant to the application cache, the important thing is [whether or not it can contact the server](http://lists.whatwg.org/htdig.cgi/help-whatwg.org/2012-February/000980.html)

Comment: After doing some additional R & D, here's what I found. When I stop IIS and request Car/Edit, Car/EditOffline is retrieved from the appCache and displayed to the user.  Once the page is served, the appCache checking event triggers followed by the obsolete event. I believe that since the browser can't retrieve a status for the manifest file, it fires the obsolete event which in turn marks the existing manifest file to be no longer needed and should be deleted.  As a result, an subsequent requests to resources stored in the appCache returns a 404 result.

Comment: According to the the w3c spec:

"If fetching the manifest fails due to a 404 or 410 response or equivalent, then run these substeps:

Mark cache group as obsolete. This cache group no longer exists for any purpose other than the processing of Document objects already associated with an application cache in the cache group."

So I was expecting any request for a resource that existed in the manifest/appCache to be fullfilled by the browser; however, based on my observations that is not the case.  Perhaps I'm interpreting the spec wrong?

Comment: @J.M. I don't think so.  If IIS isn't running it can't be returning a 404 or 410.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your initial request is for `http://localhost/Sandbox/Car`, is that the URL you then get a 404 on?  The manifest works by URL but it knows nothing about default pages or any other server configuration.  So `http://localhost/Sandbox/Car` is a different page to `http://localhost/Sandbox/Car/Index` as far as the application cache is concerned.  The view involved is largely irrelevant to the caching other than that you've included a reference to the manifest file in it.

Comment: Yes, localhost/Sandbox/Car is the URL I'm getting a 404 on.  After doing some more R & D, what I found was that if I request the URL via the address bar, I'll get a 404.  If I request the URL by clicking on a link Rendered by @Html.ActionLink, the offline resource will get served up.  What gives?

Comment: @J.M. What is the URL rendered by `@Html.ActionLink`?

Comment: /Sandbox/Car is the URL that was rendered.  I messed around with it some more and it magically worked when I requested the URL via the address bar.  I don't know what I did and I'm certain there were no code changes other than adding @Html.ActionLink.  In any case, I eventually got it to work.

Comment: @J.M. Are you sure about these URLs?  The point I'm making in my answer is that things like `/Sandbox/Car` and `/Sandbox/Car/` are different URLs.

Comment: I just took a look and they are indeed the URLs.  Could you clarify what you mean /Sandbox/Car and /Sandbox/Car being different URLs?  Are you taking about from the manifests perspective?  I believe MVC will route those URLs to the index action method by default.  And the URL that's rendered by the action link comes out to be /Sandbox/Car/Edit in both cases.

Comment: I mean that `/Sandbox/Car` and `/Sandbox/Car/` are different URLs, I'm not sure how more clearly I can say it than that.  What the server routes them to is irrelevant, it doesn't matter what MVC routes them to, they are different URLs.  If you have one of those URLs in the manifest and not the other, then only the URL in the manifest will work when offline.

Comment: After reformatting my machine, things are behaving as expected and I now understand what you're mean when you said they're different URL's.  Thanks for your help.